# Windows Git-bash fatal: Could not read from remote repository. when pushing through ssh

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh, git-bash

I'm using Windows Git-bash to push to my repository using ssh (not https). I have followed the instructions in this page

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "barghouti_since88@hotmail.com"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then copied the key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa and copied it to my ssh keys in github account by following this setup

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

But now when I try to push using

```
$git add file
$git commit -m "adding file"
$git push
```

I'm getting the following

```
FATAL ERROR: Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Please show git remote show origin.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities you can examine:

- did you "git clone" the repository with 'https' instead of 'git'? If
  you want to git push with ssh, you need to clone with ssh as well.
- is your Git for Windows version recent enough ? every once in a while, GitHub removes support for older, weaker, crypto, and your
  software needs to match the server's algorithms, which in this case
  it didn't, per the error message.
- are you using the same ssh software as git ? Git for Windows comes with ssh included, but ssh can also have been installed separately,
  on its own as OpenSSH, or included with putty, for instance. Compare
  the output of 'where ssh-keygen' with the environment variable
  GIT_SSH.

Hope this helps